# Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501 (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, performance, promise, react-native-ble-plx

I am using react-native-ble-plx library to connect to Xsens DOT sensors. The sensors transmit data at different data output rates (4Hz, 10Hz,20Hz,60Hz[default]) over Bluetooth.

When I set the Data output rate below 20Hz the application runs fine but when I set it to 60Hz, the application hangs, and all the touch options and components freeze. On the console I am able to see a warning: Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code.

I am using the monitorCharacteristics() method which returns a promise object.
What should I do so that the application doesn't freeze? Also is there a way where I can monitor the performance of the app?

```
bleManager.monitorCharacteristicForDevice(props.device.id,serviceUUID,charUUID_N,(err,char)=>{
    if (err){
        console.error(err)
    }
    console.info(char.value)  
})
```

[Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtAmD.png)

Comment: Can you please provide code snippet and console log

Comment: @AbdalrahmanValabji I have added the screenshot and code snippet in the post

Comment: dont link your console logs image, instead put your log inside the question.

Comment: is there a loop running this code,
can we use await with the function? like await bleManager.....

Comment: @AbdalrahmanValabji No

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same ... But with the startDeviceScan function ... How do you handle your list of devices up to date ? It seems that there's too much callback called ... How did you do ... In order to then select the right device to connect to

Comment: @Seba99 I used startdeviceScan on a click of button and used setTimeOut method to stop scanning after 10 seconds. I created a new list of all the detected devices which I then displayed.

Answer (score 0):

@Seba99 I used scanningOptions?: ScanOptions for handle this. reportDelay should be between 0 and 5000

```
    BleManager.scan([], 0, true, { reportDelay: 1000, phy: 
    BleScanPhyMode.ALL_SUPPORTED }).then(() => {
    // Success code
    console.log('Scan started');
    });
```

documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.Builder#setReportDelay(long)